# Django model comparison not working with float data type

Tags: python, django, model, geolocation

i am working on a project that requires location services. i'm using google's geocode(reversed) api to get detailed information from  raw coordinate(latitude and longitude) like city,province,county,...etc
my geocoding is done server side and this gives me the ability to cache the result to avoid query limit from google.
my caching table works in context of the location bounds (northwest and southeast coordinates).
i first implemented this features in PHP and MySql and it worked fine.

```
#this is the sql query to search for location within a specific bound
SELECT _mainid FROM {$this->addressCacheTable} WHERE $lat<= _nlat AND $lat>=_slat AND $lon>=_slong AND $lon<=_nlong
```

i am trying to switch to python using  django framework. and i have this

```
#this is my query statement in django 
data = Coordinates.objects.filter(nlat__lte=lat, slat__gte=lat, nlon__gte=lon, slon__lte=lon)
```

**in python, i always get an empty result even tho they are values that logical match my query. How  do i get my django code to work as my PHP/MySql did**

Please i have been stagnant for days now, any pointer in the right  direction would be most helpful. also, if there is anything wrong with my implementations or there is a better way i can go about it, i would be most grateful for a tip.

```
#Database structure with PHP and MySql
```

`CREATE TABLE "address_cache" (
"id" serial  NOT NULL REFERENCES "location_table" ("id"),
"_nlat" DECIMAL(8,6) NOT NULL,
"_nlon" DECIMAL(9,6) NOT NULL,
"_slat" DECIMAL(8,6) NOT NULL,
"_slong" DECIMAL(9,6) NOT NULL,
);`

```
#django Model for coordinates using django-mptt to model hierarchical relationship between country,state,county ......etc

    class LocationInfo(MPTTModel):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_CHAR_LENGTH, unique=True)
        parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

        class MPTTMeta:
            order_insertion_by = ['text']

        def __str__(self):
            return self.text

    class Coordinates(MPTTModel):
        nlat =models.FloatField(default=0.0)
        slat =models.FloatField(default=0.0)
        nlon = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
        slon = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
        location=TreeForeignKey(LocationInfo,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='coordinates',to_field='id')
        parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

        class MPTTMeta:
            order_insertion_by = ['location']

        def __str__(self):
            return "Bounds {NE:%f,%f SW:%f,%f} Location: %s"%(self.nlat,self.nlon,self.slat,self.slon,self.location.text)
```

Comment: Hi, weird. But I am seeing that at the raw query you are doing `lat<= _nlat` and with django ORM you are doing nlat__lte=lat, which means `_nlat<=lat `. I think you have the same for other cases. Can be this?

Comment: Can you execute `print(data.query)` which will output the SQL that Django will use. This may give some clues.

Comment: @WillKeeling i did so, that's how i can tell the results is empty

Comment: @MarcosSchroh your suggestion didn't work either

Comment: sorry @MarcosSchroh  your suggestion actually worked, i guess the logic was confusing me thanks

Comment: @clarlasparsh cool that is working !!